# Simulate CTRL+ENTER keypress on behat

Tags: javascript, behat

Following up on posts around I found that in order to fake CTRL+ENTER in behat, I should do the following.

```
$this->getSession()->executeScript("
  jQuery('form').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13, keyCode: 9, ctrlKey: true}));
");
```

I added the ctrlKey element at the side but it does not work.